# Overlap raw pointer into unique_ptr and again assign it to unique_ptr

Tags: c++11

Please let me know which constructor of unique_ptr is invoked below and why?..
I am assuming that 'move constructor' is called here but I am a bit confused as in how it can be called, as the argument to move constructor requires 'r value reference' but her I am not using any r-values.

```
int* func1()
{
   int* p = new int();
   *p = 20;
   return p;
}

int main()
{
   std::unique_ptr<int> p = std::unique_ptr<int>(func1());
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just so you know: `int* p = 20;` makes no sense. And as the address is senseless, so will the behavior be when the `std::unique_ptr` object will attempt to `delete` the memory. To me this seems like a kind of [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). What is the real problem you have that led you to write this example? What are you really trying to accomplish, and why?

Comment: As for your question itself, there's no syntactic difference between `std::unique_ptr<int>(func1())` and `std::unique_ptr<int>(new int)`. Both will invoke the same constructor.

Comment: I have edited my code above, here I just want to know which constructor will be invoked for the below line
'std::unique_ptr<int> p = std::unique_ptr<int>(func1())'

Comment: It's still the same as `std::unique_ptr<int>(new int)`, which is number 2 in [this reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/unique_ptr).

Comment: Note that code similar to this also risks memory leaks. Prefer to use `std::make_unique`, which does not risk leaks.

Answer (score 2):

This code **does not** call the move constructor of `std::unique_ptr`. It calls a specific version of the constructor in which a `unique_ptr<T>` is constructed from `T*`.

In the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/unique_ptr) of `std::unique_ptr`'s constructor, this is case number (2) ( `pointer` is an alias for `T*`, so in our case `int*`)

The **[move constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor)** can only be called with a r-value reference to an instance of the same class. 
This means `std::unique_ptr<int>` can only be move-constructed by passing it a  `std::unique_ptr<int>&&`.

Here's an example of a code that calls the move constructor, using the return value from a function.

```
std::unique_ptr<int> func() {
    return std::unique_ptr<int>(new int);
}

int main() {
   std::unique_ptr<int> my_ptr(func()); // Move-constructor called here
   return 0
}
```

Another example would use `std::move`

```
int main() {
   std::unique_ptr<int> ptr1 = std::make_unique<int>(20);
   std::unique_ptr<int> ptr2 (std::move(ptr1)); // Move constructor called here

   // At this point ptr1 has been moved from and is now nullptr
   std::cout << ptr1.get() << " " <<ptr2.get()<< " " << *ptr2 <<std::endl;
   return 0
}
```

You can see it [run live here](https://ideone.com/5gyjlL). It will print `0`, the address of `p2` and `20`.